# How to try to understand why the connection to hosts in PhpStorm occurs?

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

The situation is as follows: everything worked perfectly, PhpStorm worked without problems with `FTP` on the `Remote Host` tab. But at some point, it suddenly stopped doing it and when I open the project and try to view the contents of the host(s), this happens:

[image]

I can not click the `[...]` button to check the host(s) settings. If I connect to host(s) through another ftp client, everything works fine.

Question: how do I understand what the problem may be, and eliminate it?

Comment: 1) *"I can not click the [...] button to check the host(s) settings"* You may access them via `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`  or via `Tools | Deployment | Configuration` 2) I suggest to check `idea.log` file first (`Help | Show Log in ...`). Maybe you will need to enable detailed logging to see more details (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs). You can also try deleting that deployment entry and creating new one (sometimes helps)

Comment: @LazyOne 1) don't work, screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/cIo-DVcN3JihHJ 2) thx, will try

Comment: @LazyOne, Done, my log: https://yadi.sk/d/OM6mxbDC3JihuP

Comment: Try doing that #1 before trying connecting via FTP. But overall it might be needed to delete project settings and re-configure it from scratch (since you cannot access the settings page for some reason). I'm not sure on what's the reason is -- possibly some incompatible plugin etc (hopefully log file will give some hints -- some exceptions etc).

Comment: OK -- based on the log .. your KeePass database (where IDE stores your login/password info) is either inaccessible (file permissions, or wrong master password etc) or corrupted. You can check the path to that file at `Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | System Settings | Passwords`. Right now I suggest to close IDE, go there, backup that file (just in case) and try to open it with some another program that understands such KeePass format (to see if it's good inside). Otherwise -- just delete that file and launch IDE -- you will need to re-enter your FTP login details again.

Comment: @LazyOne Hmm, you're right, I tried to open the kdbx-file via another client, and my password (it surely is true) does not fit. Do you have any idea why this could happen? Clarification: this file is used by me from two different computers, it is accessible via cloud service.

Comment: Sorry -- no such ideas. I'm using it from one PC only. You may ask JetBrains support team directly -- use "Submit a Request" link at the top of https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm page. Perhaps check their Issue Tracker as well (the section that deals with this subsystem) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BPassword%20Safe%7D

Comment: OK thx! If you are interested in it, you can make your comments as a separate answer to my question. I'll mark it as true :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `idea.log` file the issue seems to be with KeePass file that IDE is uses to store your credentials (logins and passwords). You can check the path to that file at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | System Settings | Passwords`

It's either inaccessible (has access permissions issue .. or wrong Master password) .. or is somehow corrupted.

Try this: close IDE, go there, backup that file (just in case) and try to open it with some another program that understands such KeePass format. That's to see if it's good inside.

If it's bad/cannot be used -- just delete it and IDE will create a new one on next launch.